# Sidekiq freezes application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, rake, sidekiq

So, I have a code, part of a rake task:

```
  class DrivingStatJob < DBJob
  sidekiq_options :queue => :driving_stats, :backtrace => true

  def perform(work_order_id)
    Rails.logger.info "Calculating driving stats for work_order #{work_order_id}"
    begin
      work_order = WorkOrder.find(work_order_id)
      return unless work_order.steps.size > 1
      DrivingStat.calculate!(work_order.steps.first.location.address, work_order.steps.last.location.address)
    rescue DrivingStatService::MissingCoordinatesError
      Rails.logger.warn "Unable to fetch coorindates for work order #{work_order_id}"
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
      Rails.logger.warn "Unable to save driving stat: #{e.message}"
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      # Ignore
    rescue RuntimeError => e
      Rails.logger.warn "Unable to compute driving directions"
      Rails.logger.warn [e.message, e.backtrace].join("\n")
    end
  end
end
```

The code which calls "perform":

```
begin
  DrivingStatJob.perform_async(id) if changed
rescue Redis::CannotConnectError => e
  logger.warn "Unable to queue up driving stats job"
  logger.warn [e.message, e.backtrace].join("\n")
end
```

**The problem**: it hangs on the `DrivingStatJob.perform_async(id)`. It just hangs, without error. No log messages from "perform" function. What it could be? Redis is up without errors, sidekiq is up without errors. Redis is running on 127.0.0.1:6379, Sidekiq shows that it knows that Redis is there.

Linux Mint 15, Ruby 1.9.3, Redis 2.6, sidekiq-2.14.

Comment: Any chance that your `id` is a big data structure instead of an integer value?

Comment: No, all is fine with it. It just passes an id number.

Comment: Running the job synchronously works as expected? `DrivingStatJob.perform(id)`

Comment: Yes, changed it to self.perform and it works fine. I have a suspicion that the issue might be because of something running wrong - Redis or sidekiq. Though I have no idea what, they all keep silence, like nothing wrong happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in Redis config. It used Sentinel, turning Sentinel off for the development solved it.

Comment: Any hint as to why this solved the problem, or what led you to believe turning it off would work?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what's going on. A way to find out is to place a `debugger` in your perform method and run a sidekiq worker in foreground. That gives you a chance to step through the methods.

You will end up in the [Sidekiq::Clients push method](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/client.rb#L39). That's where it gets interesting.

```
bundle exec sidekiq
```

For 1.9 you can use the [debugger gem](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger).

Comment: Yes, I tried debug. It seems that even does not make to this point. I am not sure how it works, maybe it is stuck being waiting for connection with Redis or something.

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the routes for sidekiq from your rake task? Try it from within a controller to see if it has to do with the rake task. Maybe you are missing an include or require. If you get rid of the rescue block, does it crash and give an error?

I think you are catching the connection error for Redis but it's really trying to connect to Sidekiq which in turn uses redis.

I'm just spit balling ideas here...

Answer (score 0):

The call to perform_async hangs.  perform_async writes the job to Redis, but does not yet perform it.  I guess the job never gets to Redis so the sidekiq worker never gets the change to perform.  Hence you see no logging from the perform method.  Can you see the job in Redis?

If you're using rails you can add this to your routes.rb file to be able to examine the sidekiq queues.

```
require 'sidekiq/web'
mount Sidekiq::Web, at: '/sidekiq'
```

If you can see the job in the sidekiq queues, you'll have to start a worker to handle the perform.  If there is no job you have to check the Redis connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you are scheduling jobs under any queue except the default, you need to explicitly pass in the queue name when starting sidekiq.

```
bundle exec sidekiq -q driving_stats
```

Also you may need to make sure you are running it in the correct environment

```
bundle exec sidekiq -q driving_stats -e production
```

or

```
bundle exec sidekiq -q driving_stats RAILS_ENV=production
```

If that doesen't work for some reason, take out the sidekiq_options alltogether and run it on the default queue with a simple

```
bundle exec sidekiq
```

Also: You ARE including sidekiq worker into your parent or child class right?

```
class DBJob
  include Sidekiq::Worker
end
```